# what is the most efficient way to recreate object array by property names?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

It is simple one, but I am still wondering about it, I searched but I wanted to find the most efficient way, so come to post it.
What could be the most efficient way to recreate object (Object1 -> Object2)  in the following case in javascript?

```
Object1
[
    {col1:'value1', col2:'value1', col3:'value1', col4:'value1', col5:'value1', col6:'value1'},
    {col1:'value2', col2:'value2', col3:'value2', col4:'value2', col5:'value2', col6:'value2'},
    {col1:'value3', col2:'value3', col3:'value3', col4:'value3', col5:'value3', col6:'value3'}
]

filterColumns = ['col1', 'col3', 'col5'];

Object2 
[
    {col1:'value1', col3:'value1', col5:'value1'},
    {col1:'value2', col3:'value2', col5:'value2'},
    {col1:'value3', col3:'value3', col5:'value3'}
]
```

Comment: You can use nested loops.

Comment: `Object1.map(o => Object.fromEntries(filterColumns.map(k => [k, o[k]])))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
const
  arr = [
    {col1:'value1', col2:'value1', col3:'value1', col4:'value1', col5:'value1', col6:'value1'},
    {col1:'value2', col2:'value2', col3:'value2', col4:'value2', col5:'value2', col6:'value2'},
    {col1:'value3', col2:'value3', col3:'value3', col4:'value3', col5:'value3', col6:'value3'}
  ],
  filterColumns = ['col1', 'col3', 'col5'],
  result = arr.map(o=>filterColumns.reduce((a,c)=>(a[c]=o[c],a),{}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

you'll need to go over each object in the first array.

the reduce the properties inside the object

```js
const obj1 = [{
    col1: 'value1',
    col2: 'value1',
    col3: 'value1',
    col4: 'value1',
    col5: 'value1',
    col6: 'value1'
  },
  {
    col1: 'value2',
    col2: 'value2',
    col3: 'value2',
    col4: 'value2',
    col5: 'value2',
    col6: 'value2'
  },
  {
    col1: 'value3',
    col2: 'value3',
    col3: 'value3',
    col4: 'value3',
    col5: 'value3',
    col6: 'value3'
  }
]

const filterColumns = ['col1', 'col3', 'col5'];

// map over object one
// reduce each object into a smaller size
const result = obj1.map(obj => filterColumns.reduce((r, col) => {
  r[col] = obj[col];
  return r;
}, {})); 

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Efficient as far as developer effort would probably just be to use lodash `_.pick`: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pick

Comment: You really don't need a npm dependency for things this simple.